# installing sbt-assembly with sbt 0.11.2

Tags: scala, jar, sbt, sbt-assembly

I am trying to [install sbt-assembly by following the instructions](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) in order to make a stand-alone jar that can run on a computer without scala installed.

So far these are the steps I've taken.

I created a plugins.sbt file:

```
$ cat sbt/project/plugins.sbt 
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.7.2")
```

And I added the following to the beginning of my build.sbt file:

```
$ head -n3 sbt/build.sbt 
import AssemblyKeys._ // put this at the top of the file

seq(assemblySettings: _*)
```

But when I run sbt, I get the following error:

```
sbt/build.sbt:1: error: not found: value AssemblyKeys
import AssemblyKeys._
```

Comment: Do you get an error message that the plugin can not be downloaded?

Comment: @Christian -- No, actually, I don't get a message like that. I believe that the plugin is being downloaded.

Comment: It works here, exactly with the statements you have above (I have the plugin still in `project/plugins/build.sbt` which is now deprecated, but I doubt that this makes a difference). What happens if you do `sbt reload clean update`, does it download the plugin?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Make sure you are running sbt version at least 0.11 by typing

   `$ sbt sbt-version`

   at the bash prompt.
2. Make sure you have the plugins file set up as follows:

   ```
   $ cat sbt/project/plugins.sbt

   addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.7.2")
   ```
3. Make your build file (`build.sbt`) look like this:

   ```
   import AssemblyKeys._ 

   seq(assemblySettings: _*)

   name := "my_project"

   version := "1.0"

   scalaVersion := "2.9.1"

   libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
     "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "1.6.1" % "test",
     "commons-lang" % "commons-lang" % "2.6"
   )

   traceLevel in run := 0

   fork in run := true

   scalacOptions ++= Seq("-optimize")

   // The following is the class that will run when the jar is compiled!

   mainClass in assembly := Some("MyMain")
   ```

Comment: Sorry for newbie question, what if my project does not use build.sbt but uses special class derived from Build (I believe its sbt.Build). I want to convert it to fat-jar and I need to add the following options which I see in sample project - seq(webSettings :_*) and assemblySettings. The project is here - https://github.com/zcox/lift-jetty-fatjar

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you don't have a project/plugins folder lying around. This may prevent other mechanisms of specifying plugins from working.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't import plugin settings into `build.sbt` (**basic configuration**): 1) `build.sbt` is not a normal Scala source file 2) plugin settings are pre-imported.

So you simply should do

```
seq(assemblySettings: _*)
```

Imports are required only when you use **full/extended build configuration**.